# Create image from scratch with JMagick

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

I am using Java port of ImageMagick called [JMagick](http://downloads.jmagick.org/jmagick-doc/) .I need to be able to create a new image and write an arbitrary text chunk into it.The docs are very poor and what I managed to get so far is to write text into the image which comes from IO.Also , in all the examples I have found it seems like the very first operation ,before writing new image data , is always loading of an existing image into ImageInfo instance.How do I create an image from scratch with JMagick and then  write a text into it?

Here is what I do now :

```
 try {

        ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo();
        info.setSize("512x512");
        info.setUnits(ResolutionType.PixelsPerInchResolution);
        info.setColorspace(ColorspaceType.RGBColorspace);
        info.setBorderColor(PixelPacket.queryColorDatabase("red"));
        info.setDepth(8);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(512,512,BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        byte[] imageBytes = ((DataBufferByte) img.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        MagickImage mimage = new MagickImage(info,imageBytes);

        DrawInfo aInfo = new DrawInfo(info);
        aInfo.setFill(PixelPacket.queryColorDatabase("green"));
        aInfo.setUnderColor(PixelPacket.queryColorDatabase("yellow"));
        aInfo.setOpacity(0);
        aInfo.setPointsize(36);
        aInfo.setFont("Arial");
        aInfo.setTextAntialias(true);

        aInfo.setText("JMagick Tutorial");
        aInfo.setGeometry("+40+40");

        mimage.annotateImage(aInfo);

        mimage.setFileName("text.jpg");
        mimage.writeImage(info);


    } catch (MagickException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LWJGL_IDOMOO_SIMPLE_TEST.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

It doesn't work , the JVM crashes with access violation as it probably expects for the input image from IO.

Comment: Did you finally solve this issue?

Comment: No.I left it.Switched to C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that it may be too late for the answer.Here I wrote this simple code to create a scenario of what you asked.!

```
private void createEmptyImage() throws MagickException{
    ImageInfo newImageiInfo=new ImageInfo();
    newImageiInfo.setFileName("src\\main\\resources\\test.jpg");
    newImageiInfo.setSize("512x512");
    newImageiInfo.setUnits(ResolutionType.PixelsPerInchResolution);
    newImageiInfo.setColorspace(ColorspaceType.RGBColorspace);
    newImageiInfo.setBorderColor(PixelPacket.queryColorDatabase("red"));
    newImageiInfo.setDepth(8);

    MagickImage addTextImage = new MagickImage();
    addTextImage.allocateImage(newImageiInfo);
    addTextImage.setYResolution(480);
    addTextImage.setXResolution(640);
    addTextImage.writeImage(newImageiInfo);


    DrawInfo aInfo = new DrawInfo(newImageiInfo);

    aInfo.setFill(PixelPacket.queryColorDatabase("green"));
    aInfo.setUnderColor(PixelPacket.queryColorDatabase("yellow"));
    aInfo.setOpacity(0);
    aInfo.setPointsize(36);
    aInfo.setFont("Arial");
    aInfo.setTextAntialias(true);
    aInfo.setText("JMagick Tutorial");
    aInfo.setGeometry("+50+50");

    addTextImage.annotateImage(aInfo);
    addTextImage.setFileName("src\\main\\resources\\test-result.jpg");
    addTextImage.writeImage(newImageiInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Clojure example to create a blue image using JMagick:

```
(import '[magick MagickImage ImageInfo ColorspaceType])
(def image (MagickImage.))
(.constituteImage image 256 256 "RGB" (byte-array (take (* 3 256 256) (cycle [0 0 255]))))
(def info (ImageInfo.))
(.setSize info "256x256")
(.setDepth info 8)
(.setColorspace info ColorspaceType/RGBColorspace)
(.setFileName image "test.jpg")
(.writeImage image info)
```